# JWT token security Check with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I am using **[ruby-jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt)** gem to generate token. I am not sure it's safe or not? How can I secure my payload. I tried different ways but still can hack payload.

```
> payload = {email: "gagangami@gmail.com", token: "xyz@123"}
# Way1
> token1 = JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base, 'HS256')
#=> "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImdhZ2FuZ2FtaUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ0b2tlbiI6Inh5ekAxMjMifQ.l42W9P4lyP2XWXytu8qpasc6mAFg01Dg57Az1bfxgS8"

# Way 2
> rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
> rsa_public = rsa_private.public_key
> token2 = JWT.encode payload, rsa_private, 'RS256'
 => "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImdhZ2FuZ2FtaUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ0b2tlbiI6Inh5ekAxMjMifQ.U6DO9f9KZ_-GVhviACpXmuyc0dQUznPxZdCaaspr5JP36EweAuP8Wn_R2jvK2ahW0BR-RAh7Z9ChyIk94tDjasSbUYdoW_re299RB-ZmS0NVpCEa-g20sT-5JKCTwbD25vXYdxM4E0swQ81sKw35H5T8ZXSHsrE4bP5mA-me_Wli3hyGacb5O3esStPMdRC5r20qCoK7QW7Wl7NnZHLYjIn8k7lxsFmheNyl1l3OSLY92bxGkSyx4lom6bWqEMXSFdLWqPdKTOX9RZbNVi_6fGms79W6XXnb29htqkM1Z1h0RLXzjCODbALpa7At88xWr32IkHzwNxRJ28VAOJB3Qw"
```

If I try to decode JWT token manually without secret it gives error. works fine.

But If I paste above token `token1` and `token2` at https://jwt.io/ I am able to see payload. Is this safe way or Bug? for reference I am attaching two screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWT is not for encryption, but for identification.

The JWT generator signed the payload with a private key, you can verify if it is generated by the specific generator or not, using a public key. But the payload is not encrypted, anyone can read it.

For example. John sends you a message that "he is at home.", and signed it by his private key. Everyone can read this message but you can verify it is really sent by John, not someone else like Alice.

Comment: oh i see, got it. thanks to clear my doubt. It's not used for encryption but authenticate.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can decode, but only those who have your secret can verify the token.

> It is important to understand that the purpose of using JWT is NOT to hide or obscure data in any way. The reason why JWT are used is to prove that the sent data was actually created by an authentic source.

https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec